# Upgrade to neo4j 2.1 broke Cypher query

Tags: neo4j, upgrade, cypher

Newer version of Cypher no longer likes my OPTIONAL MATCH clause.
What is the correct version of this query for Cypher 2.1?

```
Cannot add labels or properties on a node which is already bound (line 1, column 104)
"MATCH (n1:Entity {key:"bloomberg michael"})-[r1:RELATED_TO]-(n2:Entity) 
 WITH n1, r1, n2 
 OPTIONAL MATCH (n2:Entity)-[r2:RELATED_TO]-(n3:Entity) 
 RETURN n1, r1, n2, count(n3), labels(n1), labels(n2) 
 ORDER BY n2.relevance DESC  
 LIMIT 50"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try

```
MATCH (n1:Entity {key:"bloomberg michael"})-[r1:RELATED_TO]-(n2:Entity) 
 WITH n1, r1, n2 
 OPTIONAL MATCH (n2)-[r2:RELATED_TO]-(n3:Entity) 
 RETURN n1, r1, n2, count(n3), labels(n1), labels(n2) 
 ORDER BY n2.relevance DESC  
 LIMIT 50
```

Comment: Thanks. It was the label "Entity" in the OPTIONAL MATCH clause.

Comment: in fact both "optional match" and "match" were changed in this way, I've come across this issue where we are generating "match" queries in the middleware and not knowing if the label will be defined in the queries that later use it.